# advice on displaying a business directory / member list

Tags: channel, solspace-user

I have a site with a list of members and each member is listed in a business directory.  I am using solspace user to handle my members and display their location on a map.

THe issue I have run into is that some members have more than one location so I need to come up with a method to allow them to add a second location. (and sometimes 3 or 4 additional locations)

What are my options?  add many new member fields or build a new channel to handle additional stores?

I laready have hundreds of members with their info already in there, so changing the members with a single store is not really an option.  I only need to add on the option of additional stores.

I am using this bit of code in a map widget:

```
{exp:user:users sort="asc" limit="100" group_id="5" search:shipping_region="NB" search:retailer_type="not Pending|Web"}
    {if longitude}
     {
        "properties": {                         
            "tags": [],
            "phone": "{shipping_phone}",
            "classifiers": ['a'],
            "address": "{shipping_address1}",
            "name": "{shipping_name}",
            "province": "{shipping_region}",
            "owner": "welocally",
            "postcode": "",
            "city": "{shipping_address3}",
            "country": "{shipping_country}",
            "website": "{website}"
        },
        "type": "Place",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ {longitude},{latitude} ]
        }
    },
    {/if}
```

{/exp:user:users}

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just add a matrix field for "other locations" to allow the user to define their other locations as needed, leaving your existing member location field intact (basically turning it into their "primary" location)?

Comment: can you use matrix fields as member fields? or were you thinking of using a channel for additional locations?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of User as behaving like the other channel entries as members add-ons like Zoo Visitor and Safecracker Registration.  No, I guess my suggestion would not work for you.  You may have to resort to building a channel for the additional locations, as you mentioned in your original posting.

Comment: ahh Zoo never thought of that.  I have used it on another site. This one was started before that. thanks